# Get values of one tensor from the indices of values of another tensor

Tags: pytorch

I am new to PyTorch. I have the following tensors:

```
mask = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
a    = torch.tensor([11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
b    = torch.tensor([13,16,19])
```

where `b` is a subset of `a`. I want to get those values from `b` whose mask is `0` in the `mask` tensor based on the indices of values of `b` in `a`. So the output will be:

`tensor([13, 19])`

Since the real tensors are extremely large, is there an efficient way or a PyTorch built-in function to do it?